# mysql : multiple SELECT statements in Common Table Expression

Tags: mysql, mariadb, common-table-expression

In need to combine multipe selects into one query.

```
MariaDB [aix_registry]> SELECT n.name AS WBG from entries e LEFT JOIN nodes n on n.id=e.node_id LEFT JOIN attribs a on a.id=e.attrib_id WHERE  a.name= 'LOCATION' AND e.value='Wienerberg' AND DATE(ts) = CURDATE() LIMIT 5;
+--------------------+
| WBG                |
+--------------------+
| KUG01171_TQLENTW03 |
| AIXSAWBG3          |
| AIXAPPL1EDUC       |
| KUG0114_DDAITAATU  |
| AIXSAPP03C1_HA     |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [aix_registry]> SELECT n.name AS LNZ from entries e LEFT JOIN nodes n on n.id=e.node_id LEFT JOIN attribs a on a.id=e.attrib_id WHERE  a.name= 'LOCATION' AND e.value='Gruberstrasse' AND DATE(ts) = CURDATE() LIMIT 5;
+-------------------+
| LNZ               |
+-------------------+
| ARR5S1P8_OOEGKKPR |
| AIXSAGRU2         |
| AIXSTP11R3DB      |
| STP17T2_SGKKT2    |
| ARR5S1P9_TIC      |
+-------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

output should look like this, and the solution should be expandable to any count of query. the two here are just
examples.

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
| LNZ               | WBG                |
+-------------------+--------------------+
| ARR5S1P8_OOEGKKPR | KUG01171_TQLENTW03 | 
| AIXSAGRU2         | AIXSAWBG3          | 
| AIXSTP11R3DB      | AIXAPPL1EDUC       |
| STP17T2_SGKKT2    | KUG0114_DDAITAATU  |
| ARR5S1P9_TIC      | AIXSAPP03C1_HA     |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT n.name,
                e.value, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.value 
                                   ORDER BY {expression-1}) AS rn
         from entries e 
         LEFT JOIN nodes n on n.id=e.node_id 
         LEFT JOIN attribs a on a.id=e.attrib_id 
         WHERE  a.name = 'LOCATION' 
           AND e.value IN ('Wienerberg', 'Gruberstrasse')
           AND DATE(ts) = CURRENT_DATE
         ORDER BY {expression-2}
       ),
nums AS ( SELECT 1 rn UNION 
          SELECT 2 UNION 
          SELECT 3 UNION 
          SELECT 4 UNION 
          SELECT 5
        )
SELECT t1.name LNZ, t2.name WBG
FROM nums
LEFT JOIN cte t1 ON nums.rn = t1.rn
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON nums.rn = t2.rn
WHERE t1.value = 'Gruberstrasse'
  AND t2.value = 'Wienerberg'
--  AND COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name)
ORDER BY nums.rn
```

Comment: this produces an error -> #1054 - Unknown column '???' in 'order clause'

Comment: @flynn1973 Have you replaced ORDER BY expressions placeholders with some specific expressions?

Comment: is the ORDER BY mandatory? i have no idea what i should order by.

Comment: does not work without the order by clauses -> #1052 - Column 'rn' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: @flynn1973 Imagine taht there is 10 matched rows. You want to receive only 5 of them. If you will not specify orderring you will receive some 5 of 10 rows - and the next quering may return some another 5 rows easily. This is bad. So you must use some unique ordering for to receive the same result on the same data always. It may be, for example, `e.id`... or `e.ts` if it is unique... or something else.

Comment: @flynn1973 *#1052 - Column 'rn' in order clause is ambiguous* Oops... Edited.

Comment: i removed all order clauses and it worked, so i will upvote your answer, helped me a lot, thanx. will do the fine tuning by myself

Comment: @flynn1973 *i removed all order clauses and it worked* ... producing nondeterministic result.

Comment: @flynn1973 Without the ORDER BY clauses, the result is 'indeterminate' - a bit like 'random'

Comment: one thing: this only outputs 5 items (nums AS ( SELECT 1 rn UNION 
          SELECT 2 UNION 
          SELECT 3 UNION 
          SELECT 4 UNION 
          SELECT 5
        ), how to remove this restriction, i want to get all items from the rows.

Comment: @flynn1973 Use recursive CTE instead of static SELECTs in `nums` and generate numbers from 1 to `COUNT(cte.*)`.